# Visual Studio error There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built msil and the processor architecture

Tags: c#

I have a `.NET` project and when I try to build it shows me the following error:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference `"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\mscorlib.dll"`, `"x86"`. This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.`Showpad.Salesforce`

any one help me to solve that please.

Comment: It says, clearly in my opinion, that your project is configured in a specific architecture (32bits or 64 bits) and the references (dll's used) are in a diferent architecture.

Comment: Please refrain from just pasting the error message here and hope the community will figure it out. Tell us what efforts you have made and which things you don't understand from the message.

Answer (score 2):

This pretty much tells everything "Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references", but to put it in the more plain language, some of the packages that you use in the project are built in some specific processor architecture (likely x64) and your project is set to the different processor architecture, so you need to align those two things.